# Segmentation fault, array hell?

Tags: c++

there seemed to be a lot of people with the segmentation fault problem but I couldn't seem to find any that related to my program, if there is a thread I'm sorry, I looked through multiple though and couldn't find it.

pretty much everything so far:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

const int maxLandMass = SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT;
const int landPercentage = 30;
const int maxHeight = 200;

const int numAnts = 10;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int currentLandMass = 0;
    int ants[numAnts][3]={{0}}; //x,y,pDir (0123,NESW)
    std::string rules[numAnts]={0};
    std::string rule;
    int states = 2;

    std::cout << "Which rule would you like to use? ";
    std::cin >> rule;

    if(rule == "")
    {
        rule = "RL";
    }
    else if(rule == "RND" || rule == "rnd")
    {
        std::cout << "How many states? ";
        std::cin >> states;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0;i < numAnts;i++)
    {
        ants[i][0] = rand() % SCREEN_WIDTH;
        ants[i][1] = rand() % SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        ants[i][2] = rand() % 4;
        if(rule != "RND" && rule != "rnd")
        {
            rules[i] = rule;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string tempRule;
            for(int s = 0; s < states; s++)
            {
                int r = rand() % 2;
                if(r == 0){ tempRule += "L"; }
                if(r == 1){ tempRule += "R"; }
            }
            rules[i] = tempRule;
        }
        std::cout << rules[i] << "\n";
    }

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
        else
        {
            surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        }
    }

    //Uint16 *pixels = (Uint16 *) surface->pixels;

    /////////////////////////////

    int grid[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH]={{0}};
    int heights[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH]={{0}};

    int prevState = 0;

    for(int a = 0; a < numAnts; a++)
    {
        //TODO add stuff here
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

When it runs it should start with a console window to get some input from the user then switch to an SDL window and do its thing, but the console window tells me:
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
 what():basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

I have a feeling its something to do with how I have initialised (or at least tried to) the arrays.

The part that I added last was the bit below the ////// line I made.

let me know if you will need more info, Ill get it as soon as I can, and I apologise for my programs current state, its messiness is driving me a bit mad too but (until I broke it) it worked :P

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line was causing the segfault?  What were the values in the variables when the segfault occurred? Or event better, what what the last statement executed before the segfault?

Comment: What build environment are you using?  What platform (OS; 32-bit or 64-bit)?

Comment: If I'm to debug this for you, what is SDL?

Comment: You could also try commenting-out sections of your code until the segfault goes away (or minimize it, then start uncommenting sections until the segfault occurs).

Comment: Why are you initializing your `rules` array to zeros if they're strings? The compiler pretty much tells you that zero is not a valid initializer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing your array of strings with zeros. That's an invalid initialization.

Interestingly, had you picked any other number, you'd get a clearer error message, telling you that you're doing an invalid conversion from int to const char* (which is a c-style string, and the closest valid input type std::string has a constructor for).
Unfortunately, the zero initialization is confusing your compiler to think you're actually assigning a pointer, which it may convert, but luckily it checks and sees that the pointer is NULL, and therefore bails out with the error message you saw: `basic_string::_S_construct null not valid`.

I took your code and removed all the SDL part, it compiled and reproduced the error.

I then replaced

```
std::string rules[numAnts]={0};
```

with

```
std::string rules[numAnts];
```

which uses the default constructor to create empty strings for all elements, and now it seems to work.

Comment: NULL always compares equal to zero, not just usually.

Comment: ah yeah, I knew it was something simple but couldnt really see it, just need fresh eyes sometimes :), I also changed:
    `int grid[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH]={{0}};
    int heights[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH]={{0}};`
to:
    `int grid[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH];
    int heights[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH];` and now it works :) thanks

Comment: converting `0` to pointer always produces a null pointer  (but not the other way around)

Comment: @Chris you could get into the habit of using single `{}` for initialization; it always does the right thing.

Comment: @Peter, the standard agrees, but I'm always cautious with macros, some non standard compiler may surprise you there.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, unless there's an overloaded version of the function receiving an (int), so you don't even get to convert. If you want a null ptr, use nullptrs.

Comment: @Leeor you wrote "it checks and sees that the pointer is NULL (which is usually equivalent to zero)," . The bracketed part is bogus, I don't see why you even wrote it. The pointer is always null in this code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I was being extra careful (see my reply to Peter), but ok - fixed.